# How to access the service running in an internal network?

Tags: linux, networking

I have a laptop in my home and a gateway machine in office, and there are a lot of test machines in an internal network (192.168.1.x) which can only be accessed by the gateway machine, and my laptop can access the gateway machine, but can not access those test machines directly.

In those test machines, there are a lot of services running on them, e.g., a Web GUI service which listens on 80 port. So my question is how I can access those services directly from my laptop. E.g., for that Web GUI service, can I just access it in my laptop's browser?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I removed the ssh tag as I didn't see anything that was ssh-specific to your question, and added the networking tag, in case it helps your question get better visibility.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a private network is a private area not accessible basically from Internet.

The gateway is the machine with do NAT (Network Address Translation) which means it is aware of the private network area and public network (Internet).

So if you want to access to your private network, you have to deal with the Gateway.

There are two way :

Port translating: let's say you define a port 8080 on the gateway, and every connection to this port will redirect to an internal machine and internal port ( a private web server on port 80 for exemple).

VPN, Virtual Private Network, where you connect to your gateway and establish a Virtual private network which will make your laptop belonging a a virtual lan with gateway and your private network. This way you will be able to directly connect to server inside the vpn.